# InDesign extract each page as a separate file

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

In a document where I have, say, 20 business cards front and back, and I have to export them as individual PDFs. That's 40 exports! I know that in acrobat I can extract the pages afterward, but I was wondering if there is a script or something that can do that straight out of InDesign?

Comment: I have seen the [InDesign Page Exporter Utility Script](http://www.rrdonnelley.com/prepress/prepare/indesign/indesign-exporter-utility-script.aspx) by RR Donnelly mentioned on InDesign Secrets. I haven't personally tested the script.-

Comment: Export your PDF, open it in Acrobat Pro and then go `Tools > Organise Pages` and use the `Split` function to split the document by 2 pages. It'll take you about two minutes.

Comment: Are these business cards the same design with different details on? If so, there's better ways to do that, without duplicating the design for each card.

Answer (score 2):

I recently started using the [InDesign Page Exporter Utility Script](http://www.lsccom.com/prepress/prepare/indesign/indesign-exporter-utility-script.aspx) and i confirm this does what you need. I just tried this on one of my documents and yes, you have the option to export each page as a separate PDF.